# Async test hangs in Nunit 2.6.2

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, nunit, nunit-console

I have this simple test method below.

```
[Test]
        public async Task OneSimpleTest1()
        {
            var eightBall = new EightBall();
            var answer = await eightBall.WillIWin();

            Assert.That(answer, Is.True);
        }
```

The test class looks like this

```
public class EightBall
    {
        public Task<bool> WillIWin()
        {
            return new Task<bool>(() => true);
        }
    }
```

I run the tests in Nunit 2.6.2 using the below command.

nunit-console.exe EightBall.dll /framework:net-4.5

However, the test does not seem to return and hangs forever. Is there a special way to run async tests with Nunit 2.6.2. I thought async was supported using Nunit 2.6.2

Comment: Try `Task.Run` instead of the Task constructor, or to wrap a value, `Task.FromResult`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return new Task<bool>(() => true);` creates a task but does't start it. Better use `return Task.Run(()=> true);` or `return Task.FromResult<bool>(true)`

You can also change your code to

```
public Task<bool> WillIWin()
{
    var task = new Task<bool>(() => true);
    task.Start();
    return task;
}
```

to make it work